# Fauna in deep great lakes

Tags: ecology

A significant amount of research has gone into the fauna of the deep oceans, but not so much that I can find on the deep great lakes (specifically the North American Great Lakes).  I'm interested in seeing pictures and learning more about the types of fauna in these lakes.  Can anyone provide a reference to get me going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to oceans, deep lakes are always isolated from other deep lakes by land. Therefore, one might expect different fauna in every lake, with possibly a lot of endemic species. So it may be hard to study deep lakes in general.

The ancient and deep lake Ohrid, in the former yugoslav republic of Macedonia, has been researched relatively well. Here's a [reference](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4020-9582-5_9) which will get you started. Or search "lake ohrid fauna".